# l3keys multichoice with value

Tags: expl3, l3keys

I want a package using `expl3` to accept a multiple choice list of `key=boolean` pairs to a parameter where each value is optional and defaults to `false` if not specified.

I still find generic examples of `expl3` too hard to follow. So for a concrete example let's make a package `food` that has many keys but we'll just consider one called `fruit`. This key should accept a list of actual fruit, each optionally with a value `true` or `false`. When an actual fruit is specified the key processing should create a `toggle` from `etoolbox` and set it `true` unless it explicitly has a `false` parameter value. Fruits not specified should have a `toggle` that is `false`.

I know `expl3` has `bool` but I have `expl3` overload and I forgot to buy headache pills because my LaTeX grocery list doesn't work yet. Also I want the toggles easily available in the main document without `expl3` for now.

### Minimal not working fragment

```latex
\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % for toggles

\providetoggle{fruitapple} \providetoggle{fruitbanana}
\providetoggle{fruitcherry} \providetoggle{fruitdurian}
\providetoggle{fruitelderberry} \providetoggle{fruitfig}
% yawn, there must be a way to loop over a list to make the toggles

\keys_define:nn { food }
  {
    fruit .multichoices:nn  =
    { apple, banana, cherry,
      durian, elderberry, fig
    } % ideally reuse the list of allowed fruit that made the toggles
    {
    \iow_term:x { % from l3keys manual
      You~gave~choice~'\tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl'~
      which~is~in~position~
      \int_use:N \l_keys_choice_int \c_space_tl
      in~the~list.
    }
    % some missing logic to determine the value of the current key... then
    \toggletrue{fruit\tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl}
    }
  }
```

This works for specifying a vanilla list

```latex
\usepackage[fruit={apple, banana, durian}]{food}

You gave choice 'apple' which is in position 1 in the list.
You gave choice 'banana' which is in position 2 in the list.
You gave choice 'durian' which is in position 4 in the list.

\begin{document}
\iftoggle{fruitapple}{Buy apples}{No apples}
\end{document}

Buy apples
```

but requires clean up in aisle 1 if you add any values

```latex
\usepackage[fruit={apple, banana=true, cherry=false}]{food}

You gave choice 'apple' which is in position 1 in the list.
LaTeX Error: Key 'food/fruit' accepts only a fixed set of choices.
```

As well as searching this site and the wider internet, I grepped the source code of my MikTeX installation for examples. There was nothing similar that I could find. Packages were updated yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a simple key here, the argument is actually another key-value and so if you want to use keys, you have to nest the calls:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % for toggles
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N\l_food_fruits_clist
\clist_set:Nn\l_food_fruits_clist {apple,banana,cherry,durian,elderberry,fig}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_food_fruits_clist
 { \providetoggle{fruit#1} }
 
\keys_define:nn { food }
  {
    fruit .code:n = 
     {
       \keys_set:nn { food / fruit}{ #1 } 
     }
  }

\clist_map_inline:Nn  \l_food_fruits_clist
 {
   \keys_define:nn { food/fruit }
    {
      #1 .choice:,
      #1 / true .code:n = 
        { 
          \iow_term:x { you~gave~#1~the~value~##1}
          \toggletrue {fruit#1} 
        },
      #1 / false .code:n =
        { 
         \iow_term:x { you~gave~#1~the~value~##1}
         \togglefalse{fruit#1} 
        },
      #1 .default:n = {true}
    }
 }   
 
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\ExplSyntaxOn 
 \keys_set:nn {food}{fruit={apple, banana=true, cherry=false}} 
\ExplSyntaxOff   

\iftoggle{fruitapple}{Buy apples}{No apples}

\iftoggle{fruitcherry}{Buy cherries}{No cherries}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. +1 for showing how to process a list. I'd seen `\keys_define` could be split in the source of [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). Thanks to your answer I now understand having multiple `\keys_define` makes it multi-stage processing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that using `l3keys` makes sense here since that's more designed for "code". What you should use instead are nested "property lists" since those are designed to store data.

I'm not entirely sure what sort of interface you are looking for, but you can try this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \l_food_prop
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put_from_keyval:Nn { NV, Ne }

\NewDocumentCommand \setfood { m } {
    \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { #1 }

    \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
        \prop_get:NnNF \l_tmpb_prop { ##1 } {
            \prop_clear:N \l_tmpb_prop
        }

        \prop_clear:N \l_tmpb_prop
        \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ##2 }

        \clist_map_variable:NNn \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_tl {
            \tl_if_in:NnF \l_tmpa_tl { = } {
                \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { = false }
            }
            \prop_put_from_keyval:NV \l_tmpb_prop \l_tmpa_tl
        }

        \prop_put_from_keyval:Ne \l_food_prop { ##1 = \l_tmpb_prop }
    }
}

\tl_new:N \l_food_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \iffoodexists { m m m m } {
    \prop_get:NnN \l_food_prop { #1 } \l_tmpa_prop
    \prop_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop { #2 } \l_food_tl

    \quark_if_no_value:NTF \l_food_tl {
        #4
    } {
        #3
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \foodvalue { m m } {
    \iffoodexists { #1 } { #2 } { \l_food_tl } { (empty) }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \setfood{
        fruit={
            apple,
            banana=true,
        },
        vegetable={
            avocado=false,
        },
    }

    fruit/apple: \foodvalue{fruit}{apple}

    fruit/banana: \foodvalue{fruit}{banana}

    fruit/cherry: \foodvalue{fruit}{cherry}

    vegetable/avocado: \foodvalue{vegetable}{avocado}

    \setfood{fruit={apple=true}, spice={allspice}}

    fruit/apple: \foodvalue{fruit}{apple}

    spice/allspice: \foodvalue{spice}{allspice}

    animal/aardvark: \iffoodexists{animal}{aardvark}{Aardvark!}{That's not a food!}
\end{document}
```

[image: output demonstration]

Comment: Thanks @Max Chernoff. This is a good suggestion for a command. I prefer package interfaces that use a setup command instead of parameters but in this case it had to be parameters.